# c# split and then make math operation

Tags: c#, split

The file contains

```
Londres, 14
Berlin, 11    
New York, 9    
Tokyo, 11
```

The program should read each string, remove temperature (looking for the number 
there after the comma) and find the average temperatures of 4, writing the 
screen, 4 cities temperature and the average temperature.

I tried something like this, and this only show the names of the cities but i need to know  average temperature. And i have no idea how.

```
   string cami = "";

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\ex1.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        while (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            cami = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] s = cami.Split(',');
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", s);
        }
```

Comment: What is the actual question you are asking?

Comment: Use regex then come back if you are stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"@"C:\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\ex1.txt"")
        .Select(line => line.Split(','))
        .Select(parts => new
        {
            city = parts[0],
            temperature = decimal.Parse(parts[1].Trim())
        })
        .ToArray();

Array.ForEach(data, item => Console.WriteLine(item.city));

Console.WriteLine(data.Average(item => item.temperature));
```

I get this:

```
Londres
Berlin
New York
Tokyo
11.25
```